# Encoding/Decoding AD dnsRecord values with Python

Tags: python, data-structures, dns, active-directory, ldap

I am attempting to edit Active Directory dnsRecord values via Python.  The attribute values are a binary struct - I find documentation for the struct in various places such as http://www.indented.co.uk/2009/06/18/mapping-the-dnsrecord-attribute/  I also found a few examples of Perl code for interpreting the values, such as https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Working_with_Active_Directory_encoded_LDAP_values

However I have been unsuccesful in decoding a value with Python

Example value: '\x04\x00\x01\x00\x05\xf0\x00\x00R\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00|i7\x00\xc0\xa8\x016'
 - I know this is an A record pointing the name "barbel" to 192.168.1.54

Has anyone worked with dnsRecord values in Python?

Answer (score 1):

The structure of a dnsRecord seems to be described in Microsoft's Open Specification document for DNS (MS-DNSP). Specifically for the dnsRecord it is described in section 2.3.2.2:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee898781.aspx

From the above link:

> **DataLength (2 bytes)**: An unsigned binary integer containing the
>   length, in bytes, of the Data field.
>
> **Type (2 bytes)**: The resource record's type. See DNS_RECORD_TYPE
>   (section 2.2.2.1.1).
>
> **Version (1 byte)**: The version number associated with the resource
>   record attribute. The value MUST be 0x05.
>
> **Rank (1 byte)**: The least-significant byte of one of the RANK* flag
>   values. See dwFlags (section 2.2.2.2.5).
>
> **Flags (2 bytes)**: Not used. The value MUST be 0x0000.
>
> **Serial (4 bytes)**: The serial number of the SOA record of the zone
>   containing this resource record. See DNS_RPC_RECORD_SOA (section
>   2.2.2.2.4.3).
>
> **TtlSeconds (4 bytes)**: See dwTtlSeconds (section 2.2.2.2.5). This field
>   uses big-endian byte order.
>
> **Reserved (4 bytes)**: This field is reserved for future use. The value
>   MUST be 0x00000000.
>
> **TimeStamp (4 bytes)**: See dwTimeStamp (section 2.2.2.2.5).
>
> **Data (variable)**: The resource record's data. See DNS_RPC_RECORD_DATA
>   (section 2.2.2.2.4).

The challenge of course being to decode the binary dnsRecord values from AD according to the above. As several parts also have their own sections describing their values. I have not yet had to decode these values, but hopefully this information at least gets you on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging on the document linked in @ChadSikorra's answer I created to following code:

```
import socket
import struct
for b in dnsRecords:
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dnsp/6912b338-5472-4f59-b912-0edb536b6ed8?redirectedfrom=MSDN
    dataLength, dnsRecordType, version, rank, flags, serial = \
        struct.unpack('H H B B H L', b[:12])
    ttl = struct.unpack('!L', b[12:16])
    reserved, ts = struct.unpack('L L', b[16:24])
    data = b[24:].tolist()
    print(data)
    if hex(dnsRecordType) == "0x1":
        print(socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET, b[24:]))
    elif hex(dnsRecordType) == "0x1c":
        print(socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET6, b[24:]))
```